# SweetAlert2 - Start with showLoading () and close after executing a function

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I need to open SweetAlert with a loading, execute a JS function "myFunc()" and close SweetAlert.

I invoke SweetAlert with a loading:

```
Swal.fire ({
   title: 'Wait ...',
   onBeforeOpen: () => {
     Swal.showLoading ()
   }
})
```

Where should I put myFunc () in the code?

Answer (score 6):

My thought would be that there isn't really any reason to include your function in the SweetAlertOptions object. Since you're only using SweetAlert2 to show a loading dialog while your function executes, and not getting any user input from it, you can just treat it in a procedural manner:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Wait ...',
  onBeforeOpen () {
    Swal.showLoading ()
  },
  onAfterClose () {
    Swal.hideLoading()
  },
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  allowEnterKey: false
})
myFunc()
Swal.close()
```

If you're using `async/await` don't await the initial `Swal.fire()`. You don't care about the result anyway.
If `myFunc()` is asynchronous (which it should be in order to not lock the UI thread during loading), await it and then close, or close in the resolution of the promise

```js
await myFunc()
Swal.close()
```

OR

```js
myFunc().then(result => {
  Swal.close()
})
```

Alternatively, you could call `myFunc` and `Swal.close()` in the `OnOpen` function:

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  onOpen () {
    myFunc()
    Swal.close()
  }
  ...
})
```

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  async onOpen () {
    await myFunc()
    Swal.close()
  },
  ...
})
```

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  onOpen () {
    myFunc().then(result => {
      Swal.close()
    })
  }
  ...
})
```

Comment: Calling myFunc () on onOpen reproduced what I expected, but SweetAlert did not load completely, did not darken the background of the screen.

Comment: Is `myFunc()` synchronous or asynchronous? If it's syncronous, the UI thread will get locked until completion, so the page will freeze and the loader won't spin, background won't darken, etc. If it's asynchronous, it would need to be awaited, or call `Swal.close()` when the Promise resolves.

Answer (score 1):

if you use the modal of steps, you can use willOpen option with arrow function

```
await Queue.fire({   
    title: titulo,
    html : html,
    willOpen:()=>{
operations///
            }
        })
    },
    currentProgressStep: 0,
    // optional class to show fade-in backdrop animation which was disabled in Queue mixin
    showClass: { backdrop: 'swal2-noanimation' },
    })
```